Understanding the Glivenko–Cantelli theorem (and almost sure convergence)
Let $\{X_i\}_{n\geq 1}$ be an independent sample from a cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F$. The Glivenko-Cantelli theorem relates $F$ to the empirical CDF defined as
\begin{equation}
    F_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{[X_i, \infty)}(x)
\end{equation}
The precise statement is that $\lVert F - F_n \rVert_\infty \to 0$ almost surely. From the statement of the theorem and the definition of limit, I would interpret that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a fixed $N_\epsilon$ such that $\lVert F - F_n \rVert_\infty < \epsilon$ if $n\geq N_\epsilon$.
This seems counter-intuitive to me. Consider coin tossing, that is, the case where the $\{X_i\}$ are independent Bernoulli($p=0.5$) random variables. If we fix $\epsilon=0.1$, I don't think there is any fixed $N_\epsilon$ such that $n\geq N_\epsilon$ can guarantee $\lVert F - F_n \rVert_\infty < 0.1$ with probability $1$. After all, for any integer $N_\epsilon$ there is a positive probability $2^{-N_\epsilon}$ of all Bernoulli trials giving the same result, which will result in $\lVert F - F_n \rVert_\infty = 0.5$.
Where I am going wrong in my understanding of this result? My confusion probably extends to results like the strong law of large numbers (i.e., almost sure convergence results where the "randomness" of the $\{X_i\}$ sequence seems absent).

You are misunderstanding what almost sure convergence means. $X_n\to X$ almost surely does not mean $X_n\to X$ uniformly (except possibly on a null set). It means that $X_n\to X$ pointwise (except possibly on a null set).

Maybe I was a bit unclear at the end. I understand the difference between pointwise convergence and uniform convergence, but I think my main point of confusion (which I exemplify for the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem) would also be present in results involving almost sure convergence.
By the way, I took that statement for the theorem from Wikipedia, but now that I think about it, since $|| F - F_n ||_\infty$ does not depend on $x$, I am not sure in what sense they are using the term "almost surely".

The almost sure is taken with respect to the sample of $n$ points

It's not that what you wrote is unclear. You literally wrote that you interpret almost sure convergence as uniform convergence: "I would interpret that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a fixed $N_\epsilon$ ..." That's the definition of uniform convergence.

OK, I see why you are saying that now. I think part of the confusion is that the theorem is "uniform" in some sense (it describes $||F-F_n||_\infty$) but it is almost sure in terms of the sample. I think that clarifies my question, thanks!

You can very well have a sequence of random variables $(Y_n)$ such that for each $N$, there exists a set of probability $2^{-N}$ for which $\lvert Y_N\rvert=0.5$ on this set, but this does not contradict the almost sure convergence to $0$ (for example, $Y_n=0.5\mathbf{1}_{A_n}$, where $A_n$ has probability $2^{-n}$, which converges to $0$ by the Borel-Cantelli lemma).
In fact, when the $X_i$ have a Bernoulli distribution, the uniform norm is reached at $x\in [0,1)$, which gives $$\lVert F_n-F\rVert_\infty=
\left\lvert \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{X_i=0}-\frac 12\right\rvert,$$
which goes to $0$ almost surely by the strong law of large numbers applied to the i.i.d. sequence $\left(\mathbf{1}_{X_i=0}\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$. It is true that $\lVert F_n-F\rVert_\infty$ equals $1/2$ with probability $2^{1-n}$ but the almost sure convergence does hold.
